# Net::HTTPBadResponse (wrong status line: "<html>")

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, activeadmin, mailgun

I am using Active admin to save my email templates. I am also using Mail Gun to send my emails.

The whole process works absolutely fine if I define my email boday as text such as:

```
body = "This is the text in my email"
```

If however I attempt to use the template I made in my active admin like so:

```
body = load_rendered_template("new_quote_email")
```

I get the error: **wrong status line: `'<html>'`**

The app is using SSL would this have anything to do with it? This is the same error both in production and development.